# Disable mini Calendar pull out in iOS 5 on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, calendar

I've noticed after upgrading to iOS 5 that a little pull-out sheet for the Calendar app appears on finger swipe near the top edge when inside other apps. I already disabled multi-gestures but this still occurs. Is there way to turn this off? It's annoying when using full screen drawing apps for example.

Comment: How do you reproduce that problem? I'm not altogether sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Go to any app and do a quick down swipe gesture along the top edge of the screen (around the midpoint).

Comment: why would u turn off by-far the most useful features of iOS 5 on an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be talking about the Notification Center. Does it look like the pictures in this [iOS: Understanding Notifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576) page?

If so, go to Settings -> Notifications -> Calendar, and turn off 'Notification Centre'.

Comment: Yes! That's it. But strangely turning it off doesn't make the tab go away just the content inside it.

Comment: On my iPad, which currently has no pending notifications, but I have one appointment for tomorrow morning, shows a Calendar entry, so this sounds spot-on.

Comment: AFAIK there is now way to disable the entire notification centre. It'll show up when you do that downward motion whether it has pending notifications or not.

Comment: It's supposed to be one of the major new features of iOS 5, so maybe they weren't expecting people to want to turn it off!

Comment: Maybe they will add it with the next update. I can see it being disruptive and prone to accidental interactions, especially when lending the device to a kid or something.

Comment: Like Clare said, it's one of the major new features, so I don't expect there will be a way to turn it off. I have noticed in some games however, that you need to swipe twice to get the panel. The first time, it just drops down a little tab. I think this to prevent accidental interactions, but I'm not sure if it's on purpose or just an odd bug.